# Should one who has become Bar Mitzvah during Sefirah count with a bracha?

Tags: halacha, blessing, sefirat-ha-omer, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

My younger brother is turning 13 during Sefirah. I am going to ask my Rabbi, but I am curious about the various opinions of our Gedolim.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please know that we don’t accept personal questions here; those should be directed to your Rabbi.

Comment: Good point. I'm just curious about diffirent Poskim

Comment: In that case you should check out https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/779/.